# Convering lists into scatter plots

Tags: python, file

I was wondering how I would be able to plot values from two lists that I split from a text file, into a scatterplot?

Comment: You can test the *words* in the text using - https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit

Comment: You might want to start using `with` when working with files: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Actually everything you read from a file is a string. If you want numbers you have to convert the strings to numbers. You can just discard any input that makes the conversion fail ant you will have just the numbers.

Comment: You should include a few (5-10?) lines of the file you are parsing - enough to test solutions. Also include the expected result for the example file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: When your question gets answered, please don't mutate it to ask a different question.  Just ask another question. Remember to include a [mcve] in the new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
def read_earthquake_lat_long_mag(filename):
    ifile= open(filename, "r")
    lines= ifile.readlines()
    data=[tuple(line.split()) for line in lines]
    return data[1:3]
(lat, long, mag) = read_earthquake_lat_long_mag("earthquake_all_month.csv")
```

Comment: Thank You, but this wouldn't work unfortunately. I got the following error: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
I think it is because of the index in return data[1:3], and when it is zero I still get the words when all I want is numbers.

Comment: I would need that file to help you out.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-read-csv-using-pandas-read_csv/ - if you don't mind installing a library try `pandas`'s `read_csv`.

Comment: Thank You. I'm now trying to graph this function!

Answer (score 0):

Open the file; split each line into *words*; if a word is a *number* keep it; *add* the numbers in each line to the result.

```
def read_earthquake_lat_long_mag(filename):
    result = []
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for line in file:
            numbers = []
            line = line.strip()
            line = line.split()
            for word in line:
                if word.isdigit():
                    numbers.append(word)
            if numbers:
                result.append(numbers)
    return result
```

Comment: My code is as follows and I get an error: import re
def read_earthquake_lat_long_mag(filename):
    ifile= open(filename, "r")
    lines= ifile.readlines()
    data=[tuple(re.findall(r'\d+,\d+', line)) for line in lines]
    return data[0:3]
# Ending solution
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

(lat, long, mag) = read_earthquake_lat_long_mag("earthquake_all_month.csv")

plt.scatter(long, lat)
plt.title("Earthquake Locations")
plt.show()

print(read_earthquake_lat_long_mag("earthquake_all_month.csv"))

Comment: ^^^ I was wondering if you could help me with one more thing. How would I turn the following into a scatter plot graph?

Comment: Sure - you will  need to convert the strings to floats then spend some time with the `matplotlib` documentation to figure out the best way to visuliize your data. There are **lots** of examples in [The Gallery](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/gallery/index.html#pyplot-examples) but I suggest you spend time with the [Matplotlib Tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/tutorials/index.html) so you will know how it works.  There are many SO q&a's regarding plotting with Matplotlib.

Answer (score -1):

By best guess would be using regular expression **[0-9]+**
this would check for number in the text. I dont know which language you are using but java has a function called **match**. You match it with the **regular expression** and the **text** and you will get the answer

Comment: The question has a `python` tag.

Comment: May be this code will help. import re; txt = "The rain23.44 in Spsdf3.43ain"
x = re.findall("[0-9]+\.[0-9]+", txt). This will return all the decimal numbers within a text as an array i assume.

Answer (score -1):

I think that it should work. I tried it. I dont know if you are using comma or dot.

`data=[tuple(re.findall(r'\d+,\d+', line)) for line in lines]`

You need to import re at the top of you python script.